# Trouble updating only specific fields using EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Developing a MVC 5 app.

View: I have a table which is editable. I only want to update rows that have changed. Also, I only want to update 2 fields, not all of them.

Here's the viewmodel....

```
namespace SurveyingApp.ViewModels
{
  [NotMapped]
  public class SurveyResultsViewModel
  {
    // ------ hidden
    public int EventId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Question")]
    public string SurveyQuestionText { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } // SurveyResults.Id
    [Display(Name = "Answer")]
    public string SelectedSurveyAnswer { get; set; }

    public string Comments { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Here's the update/post code...

```
  [HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(
  [Bind(Include = "Id,SelectedSurveyAnswer,Comments")]
      List<SurveyResultsViewModel> mySurveyResult)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {      
    for (int i = 0; i < mySurveyResult.Count() - 1; i++)
    {

      SurveyResult surveyResult = new SurveyResult();
      //Attach the instance so that we don't need to load it from the DB
      db.SurveyResults.Attach(surveyResult);

      //Set the Id for my model.
      surveyResult.Id = mySurveyResult[i].Id;
      //update field from the VM
      surveyResult.SurveyAnswer = mySurveyResult[i].SelectedSurveyAnswer;
      surveyResult.Comments = mySurveyResult[i].Comments;

      //Specify fields that should be updated.
      db.Entry(surveyResult).Property(x => x.SurveyAnswer).IsModified = true;
      db.Entry(surveyResult).Property(x => x.Comments).IsModified = true;

      db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
   db.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
 return View();
}
```

It works until the first .IsModified statment (for SurveyAnswer field). The error is...

> The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

I'm not trying to update the Id field. Any idea why this is happening or how I can get this to work correctly?

Comment: I think Id is foreign key and it is set to auto increment so it is automatically set the value you dont need to set Id value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be the result of you assigning a value to the Id property AFTER you attach the object. Assigning the Id before attaching it may yield better results but I haven't tested this.

In any event, I would recommend a different approach. If I was you, I would do the following:

- Loop through the list.
- Get the object from the database with EF using the key (presumably the Id field)
- Update the two fields you are interested on.
- Save the changes when the loop is done.

I don't know how many records you have. It may not be feasible to do this for performance reasons but that is what I would recommend if performance is not a concern.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide a simple example for doing this?

Comment: I moved the attach down, below where I set the id, and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: I am glad I was able to help. Sorry I missed your first question, busy day!